# Windows 11 'forgets' read only attributes immediately after it is set

Tags: windows

I am logged in as administrator
I open the properties for a particular folder on a drive in my system
The administrator has all permissions checked and set
I set the selected folder to read only
Windows then makes the changes to the files in that folder

I close the properties window for that folder, and open it again but the READ ONLY flag his checked again. I expected the READ ONLY flag to remain unchecked

The specific problem is I want to make the selected folder permanently set to READ and WRITE access, and for that status to be remembered by windows.

Comment: Run DISM / SFC and see if that fixes the issue:    .......    (1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
(2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
(3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
(4) SFC /SCANNOW
(5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.

Comment: @DanielB "What are you hoping to accomplish by making it read-only?" I'm unclear how this is related to my question. I believe I initially made it clear what I hoped to achieve. 

"I want to make the selected folder permanently set to READ and WRITE access, and for that status to be remembered by windows."

Comment: @John thanks I tried this and no change.

Comment: I misread, sorry about that. Still, my point stands: You must be trying to fix something here. The simplest case, “that annoying checkbox”, is already covered by Keith in an answer. But maybe you’re trying to write to the folder and it won’t let you? If that’s the case, please elaborate. In comments on Keith’ answer, you mention doing something in the Access Control Lists on the security tab—if you changed anything there, please describe it in your question, possibly using a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still on Win 10, but I'm guessing that thisd is one thing that hasn't changed.

The `ReadOnly` checkbox is a folder's `Properties` dialog is *not a status indicator* -- it's a tri-state switch that only affects files *within* the folder. Whenever the dialog is initally displayed, the switch always defaults to a gray square within the checkbox -- this means that when you click `OK` or `Apply`, the read-only attributes of the files within the folder will be left as they are. A checkmark sets the attribute for all files, a cleared box will clear the attribute on the files.

To set or clear the ReadOnly attriute for folders, which controls the processing of desktop.ini files and has nothing to do with read/write permissions, you need to use **cmd.exe** or **PowerShell**.

For your purposes, you want to be dealing with the permissions settings found on the `Security` tab of the folder's `Properties` dialog.

Comment: "For your purposes, you want to be dealing with the permissions settings found on the Security tab of the folder's Properties dialog." I have been, it's principally that tab that I have used to make the changes which haven't 'stuck', 

FWIW the dialogue that comes up when clicking APPLY mentions that it will affect that folder, subfolder and files.

Comment: What tab are you viewing when you say: "I close the properties window for that folder, and open it again but the READ ONLY flag his checked again. "?

Comment: it's from multiple tabs— I have tried it from both the general & security tabs

Comment: Ignore the box on the `General` tab -- but note that it is NOT checked when initally displayed, but partially filled. And I don't see any `ReadOnly` flag on the `Security` tab.

Comment: Noted, thanks. Re `ReadOnly` flag on `Security` tab, for clarification I just meant this is also somewhere I made (ownership and access) property changes from.

Answer (score 0):

> I close the properties window for that folder, and open it again but
> the READ ONLY flag his checked again. I expected the READ ONLY flag to
> remain unchecked.

I have checked here (Windows 11 Pro Production 23H2 and a Windows 10 VM and cannot see why this would occur.

Since DISM did not work and Windows 11 still is losing attributes, you need more in depth repairs.

**(1) Try a Windows 11 Repair Install:**

Go to the Windows Media Creation Link

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows11

> Windows 11 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade
> Button) and select Download.
>
> Run the downloaded file  (double click on it).  You will need a USB
> key as running the download creates a USB Key.
>
> Run Setup on the USB Key. This will launch the Repair.
>
> Proceed normally answering the prompts. The default Keep prompt is to
> Keep Everything.

**(2) Re-install Windows.**

If Repair Install does not work, then there is more serious operating system damage OR  the Windows User Profile is damaged.

In either case, normally the best ways forward is to back up and do a fresh installation of Windows 11.

Comment: I'll have to disagree here. It's not entirely clear what OP is even doing and whether anything at all would be different after reinstalling Windows or even after getting different hardware. I have yet to see any evidence that something is wrong.

Comment: My thinking is that it will be good to get Windows 11 running properly to ensure Windows 11 is not the issue.

Comment: @John Hi, thanks it is running properly, it appears this may be a Windows 'quirk', please see KeithMiller answer. It happened on Windows 10 too.

Comment: @DanielB You have yet to still answer my previous comment to you but have appeared again here? Others have understood, if you don't then there are many user's questions you can share your expertise to help.

Comment: I have tested on Windows 11 23H2 and Windows 10 and cannot make this error or quirk appear.  Answer edited

Comment: @John Noted. I could possibly try that Windows version and see. Admittedly I'm not that confident it's the cause as it's happen in Windows 10 too, but might be worth a try, thanks.

Comment: I suggest you try it.